# Why is the create-react-app command not working?

Tags: reactjs, command-line, create-react-app

Wanted to create a new react app, and ran both `npx create-react-app` and `init react-app` command in my Mac terminal but it's not working.

Tried a couple of times, but sometimes the folder is created with a `package.json` file only. Then everything stopped downloading. What could be the issue?

Screenshot of the output in the terminal:
[image: Screenshot of the output in terminal]

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, there is no problem when you initialize your react project.

I think your local network may not be good enough. To create a react app, you need to install many third-party nodes_modules then cause mistakes.

Therefore, you can try to change the npm source, such as taobao（ https://registry.npm.taobao.org ）

```bash
npm config set registry xxx
```

And then use the craete-react-app to initialize the app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My network is relatively strong, so I don't think that's an issue. It's just downloading super slowly. Could something else gone wrong? 

And may I know what's that npm source thing about?

Comment: Npm is configured to use the https://registry.npmjs.org by default. When you use the create-react-app, you will download packages from the public registry, sometimes very slowly. So I changed the npm download source to solve this problem. Reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/registry